# Why is there no option to insert a hyperlink in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I know it is possible to do so with InDesign but why doesn't Illustrator allow this even though we can insert text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustrator is not for creating interactive documents, therefore it is not a concern.

Comment: I can understand that but is it much of a concern as to not just include it as an option?

Comment: Why don't they fit beds in kitchens either, because kitchens aren't for sleeping...

Comment: You've clearly never been as drunk as me

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, if you have an hyperlink on your text box and save or print as pdf and open in Acrobat then the hyperlink will be automatically clickable.

Try it ;)

You could also use an transparent image map using the attributes panel (you need to click the options on the top right of the panel and select show all first).

[image]